Unable to deploy solana program on tutorial
I am running a tutorial on how to deploy solana programs - https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/local-rust-hello-world - but my program is unable to even deploy and stuck at the following stage -
⠚ [0/1] Finalizing transaction 4vTD2tGYSQD3UUfjj9sFVKdirGy6FRoHuALjnqtyBqBaercfNdWYPsXv3GVLre5jJX4ha8ckVrzhq1Q8AdDGoz9U"

After my command to deploy the program
solana program deploy ./target/deploy/hello_world.so

My solana version is solana-cli 1.18.12 and rust version is  rustc 1.77.2. Since there is no output of an error, I am unable to identify an issue. Can someone help? Thanks
Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
solana-program = "1.18.12"


[lib]
name = "hello_world"
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]


Lib.rs
use solana_program::{
    account_info::AccountInfo,
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    msg,
};

pub fn add(left: usize, right: usize) -> usize {
    left + right
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let result = add(2, 2);
        assert_eq!(result, 4);
    }
}

// declare and export the program's entrypoint
entrypoint!(process_instruction);

// program entrypoint's implementation
pub fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    _accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    _instruction_data: &[u8]
) -> ProgramResult {
    // log a message to the blockchain
    msg!("Hello, world!");

    // gracefully exit the program
    Ok(())
}


